# What are "avus" and "avia"?

Tags: germany, 18th-century, wurttemberg

I am working with some baptismal records in Southern Germany (Wurttemberg), second half of the 18th century. Three of the records concern siblings that all have the same godparents, who are husband and wife. In one of the three records, the godfather is identified as "avus", which I took to mean simply "grandfather", since he shares the mother's last name. In the second record, the godmother (only) is designated as "avia", and in the third record (all written in the same hand), there are no designations for either of them.

Are there  special responsibilities attached to the use of the designations "avus" and "avia", or  is this just the whim of the recorder?

Comment: "Avus" and "avia" are simply Latin terms for "grandfather" and "grandmother" respectively.  See the [Latin Genealogical Word List](https://www.familysearch.org/en/wiki/Latin_Genealogical_Word_List) from Familysearch for more useful terms that you may come across.

Comment: Gentle reminder: we should answer questions in answers and not in the comments.

Comment: @JanMurphy It's not really an answer. Just the meanings of the terms.  I have no idea whether that involved any special responsibilities in Germany in the late 18th century.